# Error when loading some pages on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, exception, android-webview

I have problem with loading some pages (that use JavaScript I think) via WebView.
When I loaded the page I got an error:

```
12-16 15:07:11.037: A/libc(1639): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1654 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

My code:

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.test);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

webView.loadUrl("http://www.zumi.pl");
```

When I set `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);` everything is loading but looks bad, so I don't want to block JavaScript.

I noticed the problem is only on Android 4.1.1. If I run it on 2.3 and 4.2 everything works perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea how can I solve that?

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace from logcat?

Comment: That's all necessary stack.

Answer (score 1):

This will disable the 3D accelerated parts of leaflet which will probably make it work but lower performance. This isn't a fix, but should at least work around it for now

```
mWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```